# React-Bootstrap form validation - Need one function per field?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using the React-Bootstrap forms. I have around 15 fields that need to be filled out in the form. Does this mean I need to have 15 validation functions (e.g validateName, validateDate etc.)?

How is this generally approached?

My data looks something like this:

```
state = {
  person : {
     name: '',
     startDate: null,
     ...
     ...
     active: null
   }
 }
```

Comment: No not required. You can have single event handler function for all the fields which sets the value to the state using each input field name and for validation you can have a submit button which will then validate all the input values. Single event handler function and single validate function is what you all need to implement

Comment: Hi Hemadri - Thanks for answering. Could you provide an example of one event handler function that can set the state when it's nested? I have seen examples for non-nested states but in this case all the states being updated lies at this.state.x.(field)

Comment: Not Sure what do you mean by nested? Why do you need nested for different input fields? I can help if you can share the relevant code about nested one

Comment: I have provided an example above. The reason the data is nested is that "Person" is passed as a prop across multiple components. I need to have the option to both change an existing "Person" within the form as well as creating a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say for eg you have 2 input fields

```
     state = {
       person : {
            name: '',
            age: 0
       },
       nameError: null,
       ageError: null
    }

    handleInput = e => {
        const { person } = this.state;
        person[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            person
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
       const { person } = this.state;
       if(person.name === null){
            this.setState({
                nameError: 'Name is required',
                ageError: null
            });
       }else if(person.age === 0){
            this.setState({
                ageError: 'Age is required',
                nameError: null
            });
       }else{
           //send the values to the backend
           //also reset both nameError and ageError here
       }      
    }

    render(){
          const { person, nameError, ageError } = this.state;
          return(
              <div>
                  <input type='text' name='name' value={person.name} onChange={e => this.handleInput(e)} />
                   {nameError}
                  <input type='number' name='age' value={person.age} onChange={e => this.handleInput(e)} />
                  {ageError}
                  <button value='Submit' onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
              </div>
          );
    }
```

Please Let me know if you have further queries. Sorry if there are any typos I answered on my mobile

Comment: This is amazing - It is not very well documented how to set nested state - Thank you! Could you add the single validation handler to your great example?

Comment: Ah I see - Just what I needed. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: There might be better approach but This is how I used to do. It’s been almost a year now since I worked on react :) so my approach may be old. Happy to help :)